# How to check whether the jigsaw puzzle is completed or not?

Tags: android, image, imageview, puzzle

i am preparing one small game like jigsaw , for that i am using 9 imageview's with 9 different images in the layout. set the images to imageview at the time of starting those are actual images, after shuffle user will do sliding the images to complete puzzle,  i want to check the modified image with actual image's, weather it's equal or not if those are equal popup a message, like gameover.

i tried like this

1.by using AND operator between the images(Drawables) but unlucky.

2.Using setLevel() for the images, compare those setLevel values with getLevel values for images after sliding still Unlucky.. here the problem is if i click on imageview one time getLevel() gives correct value, if i click more than once it gives zero value. Why it happens like this..

Please help me if you find any mistake in my code, otherwise guide me with good technique..

```
Xml code like this
<RelativeLayout
   //9 imageview's
```

in jave code like this 
if user will click on imageview it will swap the image's

```
 img_View11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {            
    public void onClick(View v)  { 

        if(img_View21.getDrawable() == default_img || 
                                    img_View12.getDrawable() == default_img) {

            System.out.println("yes");
            ++click;
            Noof_moves.setText("Moves: " +click);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView)v;                 
            d11 = iv.getDrawable();   
            prev_img = prev_imgView.getDrawable();

            la11 = d11.getLevel();
            System.out.println("d11 value is " +la11);                  

            prev_imgView.setImageDrawable(d11);                 

            img_View11.setImageDrawable(prev_img);                
            prev_imgView = img_View11;

            check();
            }
        else { System.out.println("no");  }
        }
    });

void check(){

    System.out.println("in checking condition");
    if((lb11==la11) && (lb12==la12) && (lb13==la13) && (lb21==la21) && (lb22==la22)
        && (lb23==la23) && (lb31==la31) && (lb32==la32) && (lb33==la33)) {
            Context c = getBaseContext();
            System.out.println("gameover");
            Toast.makeText(c, " GameOver ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{ System.out.println(" codition not checked "); }
} 
//here lb=level before sliding
//     la=level after sliding..
```

Comment: And some code stuff, how you are trying...

Comment: Does your puzzle use jigsaw puzzle shapes or in squares? If jigsaw, mind sharing how you did that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, here is what you do for the solution.

1. maintain a new set of drawables marking them as original drawables that you had initially.
   may be like

drawable og11 = imageView11.getDrawable(); 
do this part before shuffling. now you have original drawables, stored in the form of drawables.

1. After every click , check if og11 == imageView11.getDrawable(),... and so on for all the images in the jigsaw, if they match , it matches, else, they don't.

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

I have a simple solution. Set serial number `Integer` tags to ImageViews using View.setTag(index) before jumbling(before preparing the puzzle.) Then everytime the user makes a move, loop through all the imageviews and check if they are in order. If out of order then puzzle is not completed yet.

```
class PuzzleItem {
   Drawable puzzlepartImage;
   int correctPosition;

   public PuzzleItem(Drawable d, int index) {
      puzzlepartImage = d;
      correctPosition = index;
   }
}

ArrayList<PuzzleItem> list = new ArrayList<PuzzleItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    list.add(new PuzzleItem(drawables[i], i)); 
}
Collections.shuffle(list);

//Create the views from this list and add to the layout serially.
// set the last view as emptyview.
```

On every move:

```
void onClick(View v) {
    /* swap drawables */
    Drawable clickedDrawable = v.getDrawable();
    v.setDrawable(null);
    mEmptyView.setDrawable(clickedDrawable);
    mEmptyView = v;

    /* swap tag integers */
    Integer temp = (Integer)mEmptyView.getTag();
    mEmptyView.setTag(v.getTag());
    v.setTag(temp);

}
```

After every move check for completion:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (imgView[i].getTag() != i) break;
}
if (i == 9)// puzzle completed.
```

Comment: Create an array that holds 2 items for each position, a drawable and its index. set index for all items and then shuffle the array. Then create views out of this shuffled array. dont forget to set the indexes along with drawables.

Comment: Actually tags will move along with their drawables. Thats what should happen. The indexes should be linked to the drawables, so when we swap drawables, we swap their tags too. Views will not be moving in this case. It will work have u tried. I added the code for shuffling also. check the changes.

Comment: Thanks for help, i got answer for yashwanth, compare with drawables. any way thank's for answered.

Answer (score 0):

When you use == operator they are checking if both the objects are referencing the same object. But in your case they are 2 different objects.

You should set a tag to both the actual image and the other image. And check if they are both the same. That should work in your if condition.

For the drawable class i did notice a method setLevel and getLevel. You might be able to use this for your requirement.

Comment: both are drawables, how to set tag to image, i know how to set tag to imageview..

Comment: Hmm well there seems to be no in built method. You can extend drawable and add tag functionality yourself. Or you could set the drawable to the imageview. This has been actually asked before after i did a search http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420727/drawable-drawable

Comment: after changing one view to another view level goes to zero, why?

Comment: setLevel is actually used with the level list drawable. I just thought we could use the int values for our purpose. The best method for u is to extend the drawable class or just set the drawable to a imageview

Comment: i followed your third suggestion (setLevel). in the checking function it's not enter into the if condition..

Comment: well good that you solved. It seems the bounty did fetch you a lot answers.

Comment: yes actually i got this idea at first but at checking i done mistake.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use a gridView? and after each change, just check the items to see that images are in desired order

Comment: i tried gridview also, i faced problem at checking for sliding. and getting image from imageview.

Comment: use an adapter and in adapter add images and set tags like "image_11". and check tags to see that images are in desired order