# how to slide splitted images in grid view for making puzzle game in android?

Tags: android

Hi everyone,
               I am taking an image from camera and displayed it in an `ImageView`, next on clicking a `Button` i am splitting the image into 9 equal pieces by using following code

```
ArrayList<Bitmap>cut=new ArrayList<Bitmap>(split);
        BitmapDrawable bd=(BitmapDrawable)pic.getDrawable();
        Bitmap b=bd.getBitmap();
        Bitmap cutimage=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), true);
        rows=cols= (int) Math.sqrt(split);
        hgt=b.getHeight()/rows;
        wdt=b.getWidth()/cols;



ArrayList<Bitmap> breakedimages== getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("breaked image");
```

and i am placing all the splitted images in the Arraylist next how to move those splitted images in `GridView`. I have to jumble the splitted images in the `GridView` and after arranging all the images in grid view in correct order (actual image)then a toast should be displayed .

I have successfully splitted the images and displayed in grid view,next i cannot make them into jumble order can any one help me.

Comment: Here there is something similar.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480867/how-to-check-whether-the-jigsaw-puzzle-is-completed-or-not/7517319#7517319

Comment: the link you have provided is using different imageviews for each image but i have splitted image into 9 parts and placed in grid view andusing ArrayList<Bitmap> now my question is  how to jumble the images in gridview by clicking a button  how to slide the splitted images in gridview among themselves,and then how to compare it with the Original Arraylist<Bitmap>

Comment: how to compare the positions in the grid view such that after clicking 2 items positions in grid view it should change the images on the positions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to maintain the original position along with the bitmap. Use a class to hold these items together..

```
class PuzzleItem {
   Drawable puzzlepartImage;
   int correctPosition;

   public PuzzleItem(Drawable d, int index) {
      puzzlepartImage = d;
      correctPosition = index;
   }
}

ArrayList<PuzzleItem> list = new ArrayList<PuzzleItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    list.add(new PuzzleItem(drawables[i], i)); 
}
Collections.shuffle(list);  
// create a adapter from this list and set to grid..
```

Comment: can we show the splitted image into an imageview from gridview