# ask an imageview which id from r.java

Tags: android

I want to do nothing but ask an imageview which ID the resource has which it contains

```
if (ImgView.getItsImage().getThisID==R.drawable.theResource)
       //do something
```

I cant find it, any help greatly appreciated!

thanks, Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

ImageView v = ...;

`if(v.getDrawable().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.theResource))) {
// do something
}`

Comment: sadly didnt work, the out.printlns of the two comparing items print out something different everytime I invoke them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420727/drawable-drawable
read the answer of Itsik and Kevin Gaudin

Comment: I know, I tryed with equals too, I tryed both, many times. Thank you.